# In the He-Ne laser, if the collisions between the He and Ne atoms are inelastic, where does the lost energy go?

Tags: laser

In the He-Ne laser, if the collisions between the He and Ne atoms are inelastic, where does the lost energy go?
Does it go into heating the cavity?

Comment: It goes from an excited He atom to an excited Ne atom.

Comment: Don't conflate the kinetic energies of the atoms with their excitation (that is, with the energy states of their electron configurations.) The kinetic energy _is_ heat, but what matters for the operation of the laser is that an _excited_ He atom collides with a non-excited Ne atom, and the excitation is transferred from one atom to the other. (Don't ask _me_ how that bit actually works.)